# Vector from a surface s.t. altitude doesn't change

Tags: geometry, vectors

We have a triangle, defined by the coordinates (x,y,z) $\in \mathbb{R}^3$of its 3 vertices.  How do I find a vector, coming from C, so that when we "move" C somewhere on the vector, the length of the altitude (from C to AB) doesn't change? I can kind of imagine it coming towards us from the surface, not perpendicular, but tilted forwards. My problem is finding the vector, given **only the coordinates** of A, B and C. Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: There is no such as a 3D triangle. A triangle is a 2D object. Three points are always coplanar. Perhaps you meant a prism/tetrahedron?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a triangle living in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Are $A$ and $B$ fixed? By altitude do you mean the distance from $C$ to the line $AB$? Please clarify.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vector that satisfies your condition should be parallel to $\vec{AB}$ with starting point $C$. So if we have $A(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, $B(x_2,y_2,z_2)$, $C(x_3,y_3,z_3)$ given then $\vec{AB} = (x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,z_2-z_1)$.

Now, let $D(x,y,z)$ be the point to which we move $C$. Then we need to have $\vec{CD} // \vec{AB}$ which implies $\vec{CD} = k\cdot \vec{AB}$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. So we have
$$k\cdot(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,z_2-z_1) = (x-x_3,y-y_3,z-z_3)$$
$$\implies x = k(x_2-x_1)+x_3,\ y = k(y_2-y_1)+y_3,\ z = k(z_2-z_1)+z_3$$

**EDIT:** Now I noticed that you may be right about two such vectors. If we take $H$ as the leg of altitude on $AB$, then we can move $C$ on a circle whose center is $H$ and length of radius is $|CH|$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, I already have the parallel vector, but I need 2 vectors that satisfy the condition, so I thought the other one should be in a kind of upwards direction.

Comment: I don't think there is another vector other than parallel to $\vec{AB}$ that satisfies the condition. It is not different than that but notice that direction of the vectors are different when $k \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}^-$.

Comment: I made an edit, could you check it again, please?

Comment: You are right, I accepted it! Do you also know how can I find that H given only the coordinates of A,B,C and the lenght of CH? Is there a straight forward formula?

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, we should find the equation of the line $CH$ first, then intersect $CH$ and $AB$. If something more straightforward comes, maybe by using dot product etc. I will share with you again.